# Heroku installing sqlite3 even though it is not a dependecy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku, but it keeps getting rejected with the following output.

```
waitup$git push staging master
Counting objects: 4184, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1033/1033), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4184/4184), 1.11 MiB | 494 KiB/s, done.
Total 4184 (delta 3069), reused 4184 (delta 3069)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
       Installing rake (0.8.7)
       Installing abstract (1.0.0)
       Installing activesupport (3.0.4)
       Installing builder (2.1.2)
       Installing i18n (0.5.0)
       Installing activemodel (3.0.4)
       Installing erubis (2.6.6)
       Installing rack (1.2.2)
       Installing rack-mount (0.6.14)
       Installing rack-test (0.5.7)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.27)
       Installing actionpack (3.0.4)
       Installing mime-types (1.16)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.1)
       Installing treetop (1.4.9)
       Installing mail (2.2.19)
       Installing actionmailer (3.0.4)
       Installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) with native extensions
       Installing orm_adapter (0.0.5)
       Installing warden (1.0.4)
       Installing devise (1.3.4)
       Installing formtastic (1.2.3)
       Installing has_scope (0.5.0)
       Installing responders (0.6.4)
       Installing inherited_resources (1.2.2)
       Installing will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
       Installing inherited_views (0.0.2)
       Installing arel (2.0.9)
       Installing activerecord (3.0.4)
       Installing meta_search (1.0.5)
       Installing activeresource (3.0.4)
       Using bundler (1.2.1)
       Installing thor (0.14.6)
       Installing railties (3.0.4)
       Installing rails (3.0.4)
       Installing sass (3.1.2)
       Installing activeadmin (0.2.2)
       Installing addressable (2.2.6)
       Installing authlogic (2.1.6)
       Installing celerity (0.8.8)
       Installing culerity (0.2.15)
       Installing nokogiri (1.4.4) with native extensions
       Installing ffi (0.6.3) with native extensions
       Installing childprocess (0.1.7)
       Installing json_pure (1.5.1)
       Installing rubyzip (0.9.4)
       Installing selenium-webdriver (0.1.3)
       Installing xpath (0.1.3)
       Installing capybara (0.4.1.2)
       Installing configuration (1.2.0)
       Installing cookiejar (0.3.0)
       Installing diff-lcs (1.1.2)
       Installing json (1.5.1) with native extensions
       Installing gherkin (2.3.7) with native extensions
       Installing term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
       Installing cucumber (0.10.2)
       Installing cucumber-rails (0.3.1)
       Installing daemons (1.1.6)
       Installing database_cleaner (0.6.4)
       Installing hiredis (0.3.2) with native extensions
       Installing em-hiredis (0.1.0)
       Installing escape_utils (0.2.4) with native extensions
       Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions
       Installing em-http-request (0.3.0) with native extensions
       Installing thin (1.3.1) with native extensions
       Installing faye (0.7.1)
       Installing launchy (0.4.0)
       Installing rest-client (1.6.3)
       Installing heroku (2.2.8)
       Installing jquery-rails (1.0.7)
       Installing jwt (0.1.3)
       Installing multi_json (1.0.3)
       Installing mysql2 (0.2.7) with native extensions
       Installing rspec-core (2.5.1)
       Installing rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
       Installing rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
       Installing rspec (2.5.0)
       Installing rspec-rails (2.5.0)
       Installing seed-fu (2.0.1)
       Installing sequel (3.20.0)
       Installing sinatra (1.0)
       Installing spork (0.8.4) with native extensions
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_qlnbqtp08z3t/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_qlnbqtp08z3t/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:waiterd2-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:waiterd2-staging.git'
```

Clearly, the sqlite3 gem is the issue here. The weird part is that it's not included as a dependency in my Gemfile or Gemfile.lock.

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem 'authlogic', '3.1.3'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'faye'

group :assets do
    gem 'less'
    gem 'bourbon'
    gem 'therubyracer'
    gem 'sass-rails'
    gem 'coffee-rails'
    gem 'uglifier'
end
```

A few things stand out here. The authlogic gem installed by Heroku is not the one specified in the Gemfile. The only reason I'm suspecting the authlogic gem is because it lists sqlite3 as a development dependency. This shouldn't matter though.

When I run the exact command listed in the Heroku output on my local machine, the sqlite3 gem is not installed.

I've tried many suggestions that I found on StackOverflow and elsewhere such as removing the Gemfile.lock file and running bundler again. None of these have worked. Heroku still installs the wrong version of authlogic and attempts to install sqlite3.

How do I get Heroku to stop trying to install the sqlite3 gem?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your `Gemfile.lock`? @MaurícioLinhares Rails 3 defaults to using SQLite for new projects, but it does this by adding it to the `Gemfile`. Neither SQLite nor any other database adapter are automatically added to the dependency graph by specifying `gem 'rails'`.

Comment: Are you pushing the right branch? Your Gemfile specifies `gem 'rails', '3.1.0'` (which should be [3.1.8](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.1.0...v3.1.8) anyway), but Bundler is seeing `rails (3.0.4)`.

Comment: remove gem 'sqlite3' from gemfile .heroku uses postgresql ..sooo use gem 'pg'

Comment: sadiqxs: he specifically says that he doens't have sqlite in his gemfile.

Comment: You should check the Gemfile.lock file, maybe some gem depends on sqlite3. Another comment is you should place gem 'heroku' in group :development to prevent it from being installed in production mode, because it's not necessary :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be very simple. I was pushing the wrong branch to Heroku, so my attempts at fixing the problem were obviously ineffective.